# How can I trigger WebControls OnDisposed Event?

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, dispose, web-controls

I have set breakpoints in my `Page` `Dispose` (which overrides but then calls the base `Dispose`) method and my `OnDisposed` handler.

The `OnDisposed` handler is never called, but the `Page` `Dispose()` method is.

If you can't call the handler, what's the point of having the event?

This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192554/does-asp-net-call-dispose-on-the-page-controls-in-a-page-or-must-i-do-this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoEventWireup="true" is what you need for `OnDisposed` to be called.

[What does AutoEventWireUp page property mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680878/what-does-autoeventwireup-page-property-mean)

Here is a nice answer on why the breakpoint might not be hit.

[When OnDisposed is triggered](http://forums.asp.net/t/1664360.aspx/1?When%20OnDisposed%20is%20triggered)

> Well they're all part of the page lifecycle, but the trouble with
>   disposal is that it might happen after the page lifecycle has ended.
>   When object reference go out of scope they are left to the garbage
>   collector to dispose of, and this can happen after the page has
>   completely finished, which is why you can't guarantee to breakpoint
>   into them. You could explicitly force the disposal, but it's not
>   really going to help your situation, since these are server events
>   anyway. At least, that's what I assume you want; a way to save the
>   client side state of the page.

Comment: mine already is autoeventwiredup.  All other Events are triggered. (onunload, oninit, etc.)

Comment: thanks for pursuing this.  I actually tried "explicitly" disposing them, and that didn't work either.  As far as I'm concerned this event is useless and will only lead to confusion.

Comment: also, I don't understand the argument that you can't breakpoint into them.  Maybe not on the client-side that makes sense... but why not on the server side?  Thanks.

Comment: One other thing... one of the commenters suggested to write to a database.  Instead I attempted to write to a file in the handler.  No file was written.

Comment: Maybe something has a handle on it?  Try a memory profiler, that's the only way to truly know.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have one of those.  Have you been able to get the Dispose handler called?