# Dynamic ImageButton click event not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ImageButton _btnRemoveEmpleado = new ImageButton())
    {
        _btnRemoveEmpleado.ID = "btnOffice_1";
        _btnRemoveEmpleado.CommandArgument = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        _btnRemoveEmpleado.Height = 15;
        _btnRemoveEmpleado.Width = 15;
        _btnRemoveEmpleado.ImageUrl = "cross-icon.png";
        _btnRemoveEmpleado.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(_btnRemoveEmpleado_Click);

        this.phPartesPersonal.Controls.Add(_btnRemoveEmpleado);
    }
}

void _btnRemoveEmpleado_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string s = "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally { }
}
```

When I click on `_btnRemoveEmpleado`, the postback is executed but I never reach the `string s = "";` line. How could I execute the `_btnRemoveEmpleado_Click` code, please?

Comment: Did you set `AutoPostBack = true` on the button?

Comment: When you say "I never reach the string s", do you mean when you debug you are getting into void _btnRemoveEmpLeado_Click but only going into the catch and finally blocks?

Comment: Do not use `using` block for the `ImageButton`. As the button is disposed after the `using` block, it won't be able to handle events. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316266/event-handler-stops-working-after-dispose

Comment: DavidG, ImageButton doesn't contain a definition of "AutoPostBack" so it's not possible.

Comment: sr28, No, the _btnRemoveEmpleado_Click code is not executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `using`, controls are disposed automatically by ASP.NET, they have to live until the end of the page's lifecycle. Apart from that create your dynamic control in `Page_Init`, then it should work.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ImageButton _btnRemoveEmpleado = new ImageButton();
    _btnRemoveEmpleado.ID = "btnOffice_1";
    _btnRemoveEmpleado.CommandArgument = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    _btnRemoveEmpleado.Height = 15;
    _btnRemoveEmpleado.Width = 15;
    _btnRemoveEmpleado.ImageUrl = "cross-icon.png";
    _btnRemoveEmpleado.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(_btnRemoveEmpleado_Click);

    this.phPartesPersonal.Controls.Add(_btnRemoveEmpleado);
}
```